# pandas merge time-series with multiple levels

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm trying to re-structure a time-series in pandas of different variables (the column that currently has NaN's for the first time steps). Since it's not easy to view the code print out here, I've attached an image instead.

The goal is to align the time series of different variables in the same row instead of separate time series at the moment.

Anyone who can help with how to accomplish this?

[image: print out of my data frame]

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Hi Nihal - I've just re-uploaded the image where you can see the current data structure and what I'm trying to accomplish. Let me know if it makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple merge on the `date` column should be what you're looking for. Do a left merge with the longer (possibly `nan`-valued) time series on the left hand side:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

ts1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start=datetime.now().date(), periods=100),
                    'var1': np.repeat(np.nan, 50).tolist() + np.linspace(0, 100, 50).tolist()})
ts2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(start=datetime.now().date(), periods=50),
                    'var2': np.linspace(0, 100, 50).tolist()})
merged = ts1.merge(ts2, on='date', how='left')
```

**Output**

```
         date        var1       var2
0  2018-06-09         NaN   0.000000
1  2018-06-10         NaN   2.040816
2  2018-06-11         NaN   4.081633
3  2018-06-12         NaN   6.122449
4  2018-06-13         NaN   8.163265
5  2018-06-14         NaN  10.204082
...
96 2018-09-13   93.877551        NaN
97 2018-09-14   95.918367        NaN
98 2018-09-15   97.959184        NaN
99 2018-09-16  100.000000        NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, one question though. Before applying the merge function the length of my two time-series are 488. However, after the merge the length is only 100. Would you know the reason behind this?

Comment: This is probably due to the type of merge used. By default it retains only the *intersection* of the time indices from both dataframes. If you left merged, it will retain all the time indices from the *left hand dataframe*.

If you want to retain the *union* of all the time indices (e.g. if you want to keep all time indices, and the right hand dataframe also contains some indices not present in the left hand one), then use an outer merge. 

Great documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think need [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) like:

```
df = s.unstack(0)
```

and if column :

```
df = df['col'].unstack(0)
```